# Glimpse no longer has "Launch Now" button

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

I just installed Glimpse on a Web API project. In this [tutorial](http://blog.markvincze.com/use-glimpse-with-asp-net-web-api/), it says there's a "Launch Now" button to launch Glimpse. When I launch Glimpse on my site, I don't see the "Launch Now" button:

[image].

Has the button been removed from Glimpse? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Glimpse has never had a "Launch Now" button. I can't find a reference to "Launch Now" in the linked article either.

My guess is you want to use the "Turn Glimpse On" button.

Comment: It's about halfway down the page. Here's a screenshot I took of the article scrolled to the part where it references the "Launch Now" button: http://imgur.com/4mOIqpO . I'm aware of the "Turn Glimpse On" button, but that's not what I'm talking about. This is to open the standalone page of Glimpse when I'm using it with a Web API project. There are no views in a Web API project so the only way to profile using Glimpse is to open the Glimpse standalone window (AFAIK).

Comment: How can I open the standalone Glimpse page without a link?